# Can the C main() function be static?

Tags: c, static, linker

Can the `main()` function be declared `static` in a C program? If so then what is the use of it?

Is it possible if I use assembly code and call the `static main()` function myself (consider embedded programs)?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No.  The C spec actually says somewhere in it (I read the spec, believe it or not) that the main function cannot be static.

The reason for this is that static means "don't let anything outside this source file use this object".  The benefit is that it protects against name collisions in C when you go to link (it would be bad bad bad if you had two globals both named "is_initialized" in different files... they'd get silently merged, unless you made them static).  It also allows the compiler to perform certain optimizations that it wouldn't be able to otherwise.  These two reasons are why static is a nice thing to have.

Since you can't access static functions from outside the file, how would the OS be able to access the main function to start your program?  That's why main can't be static.

Some compilers treat "main" specially and might silently ignore you when you declare it static.

Edit: Looks like I was wrong about that the spec says main can't be static, but it does say it can't be inline in a hosted environment (if you have to ask what "hosted environment" means, then you're in one).  But on OS X and Linux, if you declare main static, then you'll get a link error because the linker can't find the definition of "main".

Comment: In theory you could use -ffreestanding to avoid linking crt0.o (or crt1.o or crti.o or whatever the heck GCC uses on your platform), write your own _start which references main, and then make main static.  That goes along with the 'if you have to ask what "hosted environment" means, then you're in one' though :)

Comment: +1 very good response, I was just going to clarify the underlying reasons, namely the fact that stubs are linked together, that rely on certain externally visible symbols

Comment: I thought the standard just required that you have an external `main` function. Does it actually forbid static-linkage `main` in other translation units?

Answer (score 11):

You could have *a* static function called `main()` in a source file, and it would probably compile, but it would not be *the* `main()` function because it would be invisible to the linker when the start-up code (crt0.o on many (older) Unix systems) calls `main()`.

Given the code:

```
static int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return(argv + argc);
}

extern int x(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return(main(argc, argv));
}
```

GCC with -Wall helpfully says:

```
 warning: 'main' is normally a non-static function
```

Yes, it can be done.  No, it is normally a mistake - and it is not *the* `main()` function.

Comment: But I wonder how this is to be allowed and should work either. `main()` is the function which is need to be called at program startup. How can one have two `main()`'s in one program? Even if you got one `main()` in one source file and it is only used there. Where does the linker know which `main()` is the "main" one to be called at program startup (assuming both have no conflicting prototypes)?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: You can have two functions with the same name — such as `widget_picker()` — in separate translation units (object files) as long as at least one of them is `static`.  The same rule applies to the name `main()`.  The difference is that the linker looks for a non-static `main()` (it doesn't care about `static` functions called `main()`; they're not visible outside the TU in which they are defined) and ensures that execution starts at the (only) non-static `main()` in the executable.

Comment: But does this answer actually follow from the standard? It is conceivable that the compiler just needs to specially mark `main` as the entry point, irrespective of its linkage. Other translation units won't be able to call a `static` `main`, but the compiler can still signal it to the linker as the entry point for the given translation unit.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot do it. If you will do it you will be unable to compile your program. Because static function is only visible within the same file, so the linker will no be able to find it and make a call of it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, no it can't. And that goes double if you ever intend to port your code to C++, as the C++ Standard specifies that main() need not actually be a function.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate.  ISO/IEC 14882:2011 Section 3.6.1 Main Function says: _A program shall contain a global function called main, which is the designated start of the program._

Answer (score 0):

C has two meanings for 'static'...

static for a local variable means it can be used globally.
static for a global variable means is can only be used in the current file.

static for functions has the exact same impact as denoting a global variable as static ... the static function IS ONLY VISIBLE IN THE CURRENT FILE ...

Thus main can NEVER be static, because it would not be able to serve as the primary entry point for the program.

Comment: You say _"static for a local variable means it can be used globally"_.  What do you mean by that?  It doesn't seem like a valid interpretation of `static` applied to a local variable (meaning a variable defined with `static` within a function).