# Why C# has static Main () but C++ has no static main

Tags: c#, c++

Out of curiosity,
C# need a static Main(), some module (probably from OS) call the Main without creating object but then why this is not  true for C++? Of course in C++, main is not part of any class. How these are called in 2 different ways from out side of my app?

Why C# has Main not  main as in C++, is it so that C# just introduced (just for naming convention) it as method should start with capital letter or some or some other reasons?

Comment: Short of the designers of C# showing up, or someone delving into their minutes (do they exist?), the reason part will be a matter of opinion.

Comment: @NickyC I wonder why, a similar question got a good response in a different space-time continuum : http://stackoverflow.com/q/11332494/3317709

Comment: @Ravi “Good response” is highly debatable – the accepted answer is flat out wrong. Here’s a better discussion: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/156336/2366 (but it doesn’t really answer *this* question).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Agreed. By "good response" I meant, many people thought that it is a meaningful question, like the one you shared. I am not a fan of the accepted answer of the thread I shared.

Comment: I am curious as to why people are downvoting this question.

Comment: @ CompuChip, probably based on my profile :-) I am sure many C++/C# developers can't  answer it

Answer (score 11):

As far as `Main` vs `main` goes, the situation is simple: Microsoft decided on `Main` to comply with its own [naming conventions on capitalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx).

The situation with `static` vs. non-`static` requires more background, though: C++ has something that C# does not have - namely, free-standing functions (i.e. functions that are not members of any class). When you apply `static` keyword to a C++ function, its meaning changes based on whether the function is a member of a class or a free-standing one.

When you apply `static` to a member function in C++, its meaning is the same as in C#, i.e. the function becomes a class function, not an instance function.

When you apply `static` to a free-standing, non-member function, the meaning changes: C++ compiler makes the function invisible from outside the given translation unit. Among other things, this makes the function invisible to the part of C++ runtime library that processes the startup and passes control to your `main` function.

Since C++ standard specifies that the entry point is through a non-member function, applying `static` to `main` would hide it from the C++ runtime, making it unusable as an entry point. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28659985/335858) for more info on what happens if you make your `main` static.

Comment: Thanks. Well explained.

Comment: Multiple entry points worth a comment?

Comment: Good answer, but the first paragraph is speculation (or at least without any reference). While `Main` complies with their naming conventions, nothing would have stopped them from making the main function an exception for consistency with C, C++ and Java, and name it `main`. I could imagine that this was subject of discussion when the language was designed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the reason is very simple and one does not have to look very far to know this reason.
C++ is downward compatible with C (well more or less). And C has a main function which is by convention the starting point of the application. With minor changes to C code you can compile c code with a C++ compiler.

C# however does not have this limitation and can therefore define a different entry point into the application by defining a static main as a member of an arbitrary class. Because C# does not have standalone functions and only instance methods and static methods.

Comment: To say that this is a “more OO way” betrays a deep misunderstanding of what OOP is.

Comment: Not at all. The main method belongs to a class whereas in C++ it does not. C++ is not deemed to be a pure OO language whereas java and C# are. Of course if one creates only static methods, I would not call this OO code. That is why I said a more OO way.

Comment: Sorry but this is just fundamentally wrong. The claim that Java or C# are purely OO is a marketing lie with no basis in reality. More to the point, “just cram everything inside a class” has got nothing to do with OOP. OOP is about a protocol for organising and performing operations on data. There are plenty of *real* purely OO languages which don’t require everything to be inside a class (e.g. Ruby).

Comment: I am using my words very carefully, I said 'deemed' I did not say is. Fact remains that main in C++ programs is there for downward compatibility with C, and that is the only reason. I think I explained the nuance by also mentioning that an app with only static methods is not OO at all.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: OOP = virtual functions = choose function implementation at run-time. That's the core point of everything. Just putting some procedural code into classes with a few private fields is not enough. Function pointers in C are much closer to pure OOP than, say, the `String` class in Java. Every `utils` package or `Utils` class ever written in Java is living proof that the language is far from being "pure OOP".

Comment: It is not like I am fighting this. I know very well that OOP is about programming towards interfaces and not objects. Fact remains that the main method in C++ is there for downward compatibility with C. I did not mean to start a debate on something I agree with. I stated myself in my second comment that a program with all static methods in not OO. I agree with you that virtual is the key, because that is what makes it possible to program towards interfaces that can have a different implementation which the user of the interface does not need to know about.